# O que é Malha Digital Inteligente (Digital Mesh)?

Tags: iot, ciência-de-dados

De forma simples e objetiva, o que seria esse termo que muitos dizem ser uma tendência na área da tecnologia da informação?

Answer (score -1):

É uma tendências de software que estão permitindo o entrelaçamento de pessoas, dispositivos, conteúdo e serviços. O resultado é o que o Gartner chama de malha digital inteligente:

- Inteligente: como a IA está se infiltrando em praticamente todas as tecnologias e com um foco definido e bem definido pode permitir sistemas mais dinâmicos, flexíveis e potencialmente autônomos.
- Digital : mistura os mundos virtual e real para criar um ambiente imersivo e conectado digitalmente.
- Malha : as conexões entre um conjunto crescente de pessoas, negócios, dispositivos, conteúdo e serviços para fornecer resultados digitais.

Na minha opinião a junção de todos esses culminará(num futuro breve) no laço neural que a junção de maquina e humano(Olha o projeto da neuralink):D